# Visual Studio 2012 C++ Compiled Program isn't loading files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I've got a C++ program that is exhibiting some weird behaviour when I try to run it from the IDE. One of the things this program needs to do is load some files that are in the same directory it is. I've placed these files in Visual Studio's output directory so that it can find them.

However, when I run the program from the IDE using Ctrl+F5 ( Start without debugging ), the program can't find the files it needs.

Oddly enough if I go to the Windows Explorer and manually find the generated .exe and run it, the program finds the files and runs normally.

How do I fix it so that I can run the program from the IDE and have it still find its files?

Comment: The files need to be in the same directory as the .vcxproj file when you run from the IDE.

Comment: You can also change the working directory for the debugger.  You could also use the `SetCurrentDirectory` function in the program to set it to where the application is.

Comment: Look at the project/solution's "Debug" properties to see what directory it executes in.

Comment: kfsone's solution worked for me! Thanks everybody.

Comment: This is also going to happen after that program leaves your machine.  The fundamental mistake you are making is not specifying the full path of the file.  Use GetModuleFileName(nullptr, ...) to find the EXE directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the "working directory" to the directory with the files.  I assume you want to keep the working directory to be the same as the executable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kcw4dzyf.aspx  Outlines the settings for debugging.